# How do I clear a String local to a method? My text gets appended everytime the method is run

Tags: java

I have a local String in a method like so:

```
String jString = new String();
```

or

```
String jString = "";
```

The result is the same.

Later in the method I append:

```
for(int i = 0; i != someArrayList.size(); ++i) {
    jString += someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";
}
```

Everytime the method is run, the text from getText() gets appended to jString.

Why is this and how can I prevent it from happening?
Thanks!

OK edit. This is basically what happens. Either that or you tell me it is impossible to get the results I described with this code.

```
public void requestData()  {
   String jString = new String();
   for(int i = 0; i != someArrayList.size(); ++i) {
      jString += someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";
      }
}
```

Say inside the array I have values ["a", "b", "c"]. When I run the method jString contains:
a
b
c
Next time I run it, I want it to be the new contents of the array not
a
b
c
plus the new contents.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on from just this snippet. Please post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok modified. Please bear with me if I do something wrong. It's my first question on here. But happy to learn.

Comment: Glad that you have a good attitude about it.  I appreciate a commitment to learning.

Comment: I have to say I am stumped! This was solved so fast with the help of so many members and THE Jon Skeet commented after 5 minutes :) Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code which you have written, it will add the text from the array to the jString variable which you cant prevent. But if you don't want that to happen then if you can mention about the logic of your code then according to that we can help you.

EDIT: According to your code it will work as expected by you. So i think the problem is with the array which you are accessing. 
ie. for the 1st if array contains a,b,c then jstring = "abc";
and for the 2nd time if array contains a,b,c,d,e, then jString="abcde";

Comment: This is true, if you are not clearing the array between calls.

Comment: Thats it! Facepalm. There is a class member array with objects that are added again and again inside this method. Thanks you!

Comment: Now get that `StringBuilder` object in there!

Answer (score 1):

**The code you describe does exactly as you require.**

```
public void requestData()  {
  String jString = new String();
  for(int i = 0; i != someArrayList.size(); ++i) {
    jString += someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";
  }
}
```

When you call this method, it will create a new (empty) `jString` and then append each item in the list to it, separated by a newline character.  There is no way that `jString` could continue to carry the value from the previous call, since the variable leaves and re-enters scope when the method returns and is called again.

By the way, you should still use a `StringBuilder` object.

```
public void requestData() {
  StringBuilder jStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < someArrayList.size(); i++) {
    jStringBuilder.append(someArrayList.get(i).getText()).append('\n');
  }
  String jString = jStringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `jString` variable is not local in the method and the method `+=`s it on every call. You should:

1. Make it local and return the constructed value, or
2. Use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` (the best choice not to put burden to garbage collector).

Comment: GK pointed me to it, but I will keep the StringBuffer in mind. THX

Answer (score 0):

**Check where the `jString` is being defined.**

Based on the results, I am guessing that you have defined it like the first code block here.

```
public class MyClass {
  String jString = new String();

  public void myMethod() {
    for(int i = 0; i != someArrayList.size(); ++i) {
      jString += someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

This does not clear the `jString` each time the method is called.  The `jString` is initialized when the class is instantiated.  Each call to the method keeps adding on to it.

I suspect that what you really want is something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
  public void myMethod() {
    String jString = new String();

    for(int i = 0; i != someArrayList.size(); ++i) {
      jString += someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

If you declare the `jString` inside the method, then it will clear each time.

The second example is the one where the string is "local to the method".  In the first example, the string is a property of the class.

One other point of importance.  When appending strings like this, it is wise to use a `StringBuilder` class.  This will cause a lot less memory to be used when building the string.  There are other questions on SO that explain why, if you are interested.

Comment: according to the description of the question he already has a jString as a method variable.

Comment: If this is true, then the results would not be as he described.  I think it's more likely that the OP is confused and is using poor terminology.

Comment: I modified the original question. The String is a method variable. But at the same time it is very possible that I am confused and using poor terminology :)

Answer (score -1):

remove the `+`

> jString =
>   someArrayList.get(i).getText() + "\n";

Will stop appending it. And just replace jString each time, but I doubt if this is what you want either.

Comment: Is that really what he wants?

Comment: @dacwe don't ask me, but thats why its appending.

Comment: This will be break the logic, since it makes a multi-row text from an array in each call.

Comment: @NimChimpsky that's the same as `jString = someArrayList.get(someArrayList.size() - 1).getText() + "\n";`

Comment: @khachik, yeah I know that and you know that, but thats what the question is. "I have a created a loop that appends text, I want to stop it appending text" ...

Comment: @NimChimbsky I want it to append inside the for loop. I just want the String to clear when the method (where all this happens) is run. Hope I made myself more clear.

Comment: -1 Missed the point.  That loop is pointless without the `+=`.  The problem is elsewhere.